# Stop scheduled JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript

I have a function, where I define lots of setTimeout() functions .
When user presses the button, it's starting the execution.

How can I cancel it ?

Is there any way to cancel ALL timeouts (assuming that I have multiple without the name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// start timer
var timer = setTimeout(...);

// cancel timer
clearTimeout(timer);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Pass the timer ID returned by [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

Use clearTimeout:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){ alert("hello!"); }, 3000);   

...

clearTimeout(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function setTimeout() returns an ID you can use to clear the timeout. You'll have to keep track of the timeouts, and clear them manually:

```
var timeoutID = setTimeout( scheduledFunction, time );

// do stuff...

//clear the timeout:
clearTimeout( timeoutID  );
```